# How manufacturer optimize their Windows 10 ? (or IT repair company)

Tags: windows-10

Like it's says in the title, I want to know how they do to make such a quick and smooth Windows 10 ?

For example, I'm working with an Acer laptop, and it's very quick to boot, to exit sleep mode. I'm also getting my hand on an HP laptop, that is the same thing, really quick, even with a Ryzen 3.
An other example was a friend that requiered IT company to bring is pc back to life. He has a really, really old pc (very basic with an Intel Pentium) from 10y ago I think, and it's was running W10 like nothing. I ended up getting this pc, and with an SSD, and a custom W10 iso I make, I can't reproduce such performances he was having :/

I know different way to optimize W10, but with some compromises. If you can explain or give your tips to optimize this OS like they did, I will be glad to get those !

Comment: be more specific and give example of such a company

Comment: Question edited with lot more details

Comment: What methods of optimization did you use already? Did you try Autoruns? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: I gonna take a look at that, thanks. To optimize W10, I use a Debloat script, 0&0Shutup10 to disabled W10 options, and all that on a custom W10 image create with WinToolkit (with older W version like 1909 or 2004).

Comment: I can guarantee you that running that you will eventually regret running that Debloat script when your unable to install feature updates or some other feature Windows doesn’t work

Comment: You can choose what you want to disable. For me, I never got problem with update even after running the script but I believe you. Just W10 can get error on Update with pure "Vanilla" install.

Comment: Take a look at: https://christitus.com/windows-10-optimization-guide/

Comment: I'm gonna do it, thanks ! I love this guy tutorials about W-optimization. Found them very useful (for my case at least)